# go exec command security linting messages using golangci

Tags: go

I'm adding a linter for `gosec` for golangci-lint and everything is covered except the following:

```
exec.Command(params[0], params[1:]…)
```

I know that I can disable this lint but I don't want to do it. Is there a way to fix the code to satisfy this lint?

the error is:

````
 G204: Subprocess launched with function call as argument or cmd arguments ```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hardcode a command call. There are [no other options](https://github.com/securego/gosec/blob/master/rules/subproc.go#L42:L57) AFAIS.

Update: starting from version 1.40 you `gosec` options are customizable, see example config `.golangci.example.yml` in https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint repository.

```yaml
linters-settings:
  gosec:
    # To select a subset of rules to run.
    # Available rules: https://github.com/securego/gosec#available-rules
    includes:
      - G401
      - G306
      - G101
    # To specify a set of rules to explicitly exclude.
    # Available rules: https://github.com/securego/gosec#available-rules
    excludes:
      - G204
    # To specify the configuration of rules.
    # The configuration of rules is not fully documented by gosec:
    # https://github.com/securego/gosec#configuration
    # https://github.com/securego/gosec/blob/569328eade2ccbad4ce2d0f21ee158ab5356a5cf/rules/rulelist.go#L60-L102
    config:
      G306: "0600"
      G101:
        pattern: "(?i)example"
        ignore_entropy: false
        entropy_threshold: "80.0"
        per_char_threshold: "3.0"
        truncate: "32"
```

Comment: This is your answer - you running different commands. What are your other options that not disable it? rewrite functionality, so `gosec` wouldn't complain. or you can disable message.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of disabling the linter you could exclude the specific line with an annotation;

```golang
exec.Command(params[0], params[1:]...) //nolint:gosec
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to disable *only* this check, you can

> exec.Command(params[0], params[1:]...) // #nosec G204